# Limit hover help on field to single page layout; don't show on other page layouts

Tags: page-layout, help, helptext

I was wondering if it's possible to display an help text linked to a field to one page layout only.

I need to use a different help text according to the page layout. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know Help Text is entered at the time of creating the field, so its not possible to display different types of help texts for same field in different layouts.

Answer (score 1):

For the detail page, you can show a formula field just beneath or next to the field in question. This would let you show the text just on one layout. This won't help you if you need to display the text on the edit page.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new field and give it the same label as the other field (but a different API Name). This new field will have help text on it, and this will be the field you put on that one page layout.

You just need to create a workflow rule or two to make sure that the information is synched between those two fields whenever the record is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on a visualforce page with the apex:pageBlockSectionItem using the helpText attribute.